# How to get pictures to appear again when I post a link on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, images

When I post text on Facebook with a link in it like this:

> text text text text http://someurl...

it would always go to the site and give me a choice of pictures on that site to display with the post. But since about two weeks ago, it seems to go to the site, shows some kind of AJAX in progress graphic, but then always comes back empty and suggests no pictures.

How can I get Facebook to show me an array of pictures to choose from that are on the website I link to again?

Comment: This worked for me the other day.  Are you sure it happens for EVERY site you try to post a link to?

Comment: It does not happen for every site. Only certain sites that are not setup properly or have some competing script. He will need to post the site/s in question

Comment: yes, it even happens on every site I try, I thought it was because there were too many pictures on them, but it even happens on this site, where there is just one picture: http://tanguay.info/blog/index.php?i=2010-07-11-memoryMethod

Comment: Try stripping it even more with out the php style posts just a static page with one image and make sure the proper doctype is defined, I was not able to see one when doing markup validation. Try it like this https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5330881/test.html (note this is html5 doctype)

Comment: Can you get the functionality working if you access the site through a different browser/machine/etc? It might just be a cache/cookie issue...

Comment: @tomatosandwich I tried IE and chrome, same thing

Comment: @phwd your test page worked!, gives me some things to try, thanks

Comment: @phwd but I copied over your minimalistic HTML5 headers to the site I'm trying to post http://www.tanguay.info/run and it still doesn't work, same thing: runs for awhile then returns no picture suggestions, I have alt tags in all images, what else is there?, strange.

Comment: It is your relative src to the image that is problem putting the full path will make it work.

Comment: @Edward Tanguay have you tried the full image path ? Let me know if that was the problem. I got your page to work when I switched the relative sources to the full path.

Comment: @phwd YES! that was it, interesting that facebook used to be able to read relative image paths, ok, but that fixes the problem, thanks

Comment: @phwd please post an answer quick so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests (& discussions in the comments) with the pages in question, it seems that Facebook Publisher works only with full paths on images (maybe you can file this as a bug).

Instead of using the relative path, use the full path to your images. This will allow you to get an array of pictures from the website in question.